# Hibernate beginner - Duplicate import

Tags: java, hibernate

I am following the tutorials from pluralsight - introduction to hibernate and encountered errors when persisting my object.

I have re-watch several times the videos and I have followed every step correctly, but i could not figure out where the issue was.

Can anyone advise what have I done incorrectly?

Note: I downloaded hibernate 4.3.5 and copy hibernate-release-4.3.5.Final\lib\required to the \lib folder of my eclipse project.

Error:

```
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:03 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:03 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/simpleprogrammer/User.hbm.xml
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/simpleprogrammer/User.hbm.xml
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/]
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=appuser, password=****}
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl addImport
INFO: HHH000071: Duplicate import: com.simpleprogrammer.User -> com.simpleprogrammer.User
Aug 02, 2014 10:49:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl addImport
INFO: HHH000071: Duplicate import: com.simpleprogrammer.User -> User
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/simpleprogrammer/User.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.simpleprogrammer.HibernateUtilities.<clinit>(HibernateUtilities.java:22)
    at com.simpleprogrammer.Program.main(Program.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/simpleprogrammer/User.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3762)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3751)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3739)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at com.simpleprogrammer.HibernateUtilities.<clinit>(HibernateUtilities.java:17)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.simpleprogrammer.User
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addClass(Configuration.java:2835)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3759)
    ... 6 more
```

My mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Aug 2, 2014 9:15:11 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.simpleprogrammer.User" table="USERS">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="total" type="int">
            <column name="TOTAL" />
        </property>
        <property name="goal" type="int">
            <column name="GOAL" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">appuser</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">protein_tracker</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping resource="com/simpleprogrammer/User.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My POJO

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int total;
    private int goal;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    public int getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }
    public void setGoal(int goal) {
        this.goal = goal;
    }   
}
```

My main class:

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Joe");
        user.setGoal(250);
        session.save(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        System.out.println("Hello World");
        HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Comment: seems that you get NullPointerException on the line, where you are trying to get Session instance. `Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();` Check out the `HibernateUtilities` class. Perhaps the problem is located into it.

Comment: You're mixing major versions, as clearly stated in the error message. You need to use all Hibernate 4; look at that migration guide to see what changes you need to make.

Comment: Is there anything else in the stacktrace after "at com.simpleprogrammer.Program.main(Program.java:9)"

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I downloaded hibernate 4.3.5 and copy hibernate-release-4.3.5.Final\lib\required to the \lib folder of my eclipse project

Comment: @kharyam nothing else.

Comment: @chrylis This is an entirely new project. I am using hibernate 4.3.5

Comment: Looks like you have not set the id in the java file. I'd start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtilities {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

I used the incorrect method to get the SessionFactory